# Autocompletion suggests perfect value but then it removes it - how can I avoid it?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

When I use code completion like

```
return new MyClass.someConstructor(something, value)
```

I can select the constructor after writing a few characters of `MyClass` with <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then I step through the parameter list pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
I don't change anything because the suggested values are already correct.
When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (on `value`) and then write the `;` or `:` `value` get's removed (optional positional parameter).

Is there an easy way (keyboard shortcut) to keep the suggested value without overwriting it manually?

Comment: haven't found a way to do exactly what you want, but pressing undo then redo as soon as the suggested values come up will leave the values and exit the autocomplete

Comment: Better than nothing ;) I'll try it.